# How to convert .dat to .csv using python?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

**I have a file.dat which looks like:**

```
id       | user_id | venue_id | latitude  | longitude | created_at

---------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------

984301   |2041916  |5222      |           |           |2012-04-21 17:39:01

984222   |15824    |5222      |38.8951118 |-77.0363658|2012-04-21 17:43:47

984315   |1764391  |5222      |           |           |2012-04-21 17:37:18

984234   |44652    |5222      |33.800745  |-84.41052  | 2012-04-21 17:43:43
```

**I need to get csv file with deleted empty latitude and longtitude rows, like:**

```
id,user_id,venue_id,latitude,longitude,created_at

984222,15824,5222,38.8951118,-77.0363658,2012-04-21T17:43:47

984234,44652,5222,33.800745,-84.41052,2012-04-21T17:43:43

984291,105054,5222,45.5234515,-122.6762071,2012-04-21T17:39:22
```

**I try to do that, using next code:**

```
with open('file.dat', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLine = line.strip('|').split()
        newLines.append(newLine)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

But all the same I get a csv file with "|" symbols and empty latitude/longtitude rows.
Where is mistake?
In general I need to use resulting csv-file in DateFrame, so maybe there is some way to reduce number of actions.

Comment: didn't you meant   `newLine = line.strip().split('|')` instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes leading and trailing characters from a string.
You want to split the lines on `"|"`, then strip each element of the resulting list:

```
import csv

with open('file.dat') as dat_file, open('file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for line in dat_file:
        row = [field.strip() for field in line.split('|')]
        if len(row) == 6 and row[3] and row[4]:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.dat', sep='|', header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
data.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: data.dropna(inplace=True) drop all rows with NaN values. For delete header "separator"  better use data.drop(0)

Answer (score 2):

I used standard python features without pre-processing data. I got an idea from one of the previous answers and improved it. If data headers contain spaces (it is often the situation in CSV) we should determine column names by ourselves and skip line 1 with headers.
After that, we can remove NaN values only by specific columns.

```
data = pd.read_csv("checkins.dat", sep='|', header=None, skiprows=1,
                   low_memory = False, skipinitialspace=True,
                   names=['id','user_id','venue_id','latitude','longitude','created_at'])
data.dropna(subset=['latitude', 'longitude'], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()` without parameters will result in splitting after a space
example `"test1 test2".split()` results in `["test1", "test2"]`

instead, try this:

```
newLine = line.split("|")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to use a `map()` function instead of list comprehensions as it must be working faster. Also writing a csv-file is easy with `csv` module.

```
import csv
with open('file.dat', 'r') as fin:
with open('file.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        newline = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        if len(newline) == 6 and newline[3] and newline[4]:
            csv.writer(fout).writerow(newline)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: 1. The syntax is invalid: the block starting from line 3 needs to be indented one level deeper.

Comment: 2. Line 6 is invalid in Python 3, because `map` is an interator and it's not possible to get its `len`.

Comment: 3. In Python 3, opening a file for writing CSV requires passing `newline=''`. Otherwise, the output will be interspersed with empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.dat") as f:
    with open("filename.csv", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

This can be used to convert a .dat file to .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Combining previous answers I wrote my code for **Python 2.7**:

```
import csv

lat_index = 3
lon_index = 4
fields_num = 6
csv_counter = 0

with open("checkins.dat") as dat_file:
    with open("checkins.csv", "w") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for dat_line in dat_file:
            new_line = map(str.strip, dat_line.split('|'))
            if len(new_line) == fields_num and new_line[lat_index] and new_line[lon_index]:
                csv_writer.writerow(new_line)
                csv_counter += 1

print("Done. Total rows written: {:,}".format(csv_counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.dat',sep='::',names=list_for_names_of_columns)
```