# Convert all DAT files in a folder to CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did a bit of Googling and came across the script below, to convert DAT files into CSV files.

```
import csv
import idlsave
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext

dat_folder = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\dat\\"
csv_folder = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\csv\\"

onlyfilenames = [f for f in listdir(dat_folder) if isfile(join(dat_folder,f))]
for fullfilename in onlyfilenames:
    file_name, file_extension = splitext(fullfilename)
    if file_extension == ".DAT":
        input_file = idlsave.read(dat_folder + fullfilename)
        n = input_file["raw"]
        with open(join(csv_folder, file_name + ".CSV"), "w", newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(n)
```

The code looks like it would work, and the logic seems sound, but when I run it I get this error message:

`Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'10'`

All file names and extensions are in upper case.  Not sure if that makes any difference.  I Googled the error and didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: `n` is raw as per your code, or in other words in bytes. That may be cause of the error. U will need to put a logic in place to convert it proper data-types (str, int etc) before writing using writer.

Comment: Also checkout this  answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845032/how-to-convert-dat-to-csv-using-python

Comment: The only line that can throw this error in this code is `idlsave.read(...)`. And the error means that your `.DAT` file is not in a format that `idlsave` can process.

Comment: You are assuming that all `.dat` files are the same.  It's a fairly generic file extension.  You've got yourself a file that's not what you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Anil_M, that helped a lot!  Here is my final solution.

```
import csv
import idlsave
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext

dat_folder = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\dat\\"
csv_folder = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\csv\\"

onlyfilenames = [f for f in listdir(dat_folder) if isfile(join(dat_folder,f))]
for fullfilename in onlyfilenames:
    file_name, file_extension = splitext(fullfilename)
    if file_extension == ".DAT":
        with open(join(dat_folder + fullfilename)) as f:
            with open(join(csv_folder, file_name + ".CSV"), "w") as f1:
                for line in f:
                    f1.write(line)
```